# Android - Oauth2.0 - поиск хорошего примера

Tags: android, github, oauth2

Подскажите пример приложения под android с хорошо реализованной Oauth 2.0.
Желательно github.
Спасибо

Да и хочется увидеть пример с использованием gson+retrofit+okhttp

Comment: google -> android oauth2 github

1)https://github.com/wuman/android-oauth-client
2)https://github.com/danielsz/android-oauth2-client

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но первая трудно читается новичкам.

Comment: "Подскажите пример приложения под android с хорошо реализованной Oauth 2.0. Желательно github. Спасибо" -> 
Про новичков в изначальном вопросе и слова не было.

Comment: это да, извиняюсь